# R - count occurrences in long vectors

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe that is 6249 rows long, filled with character-type data and will likely get a lot bigger.

I want to count the number of occurrences of each string. Normally I'd use `table(df)` 
or

```
count(df)
```

but they both seem to stop after 250 rows.

Is there a different function or a way to force count() or table() to continue for 6000+ results?

Comment: are you just trying to count the rows in the data frame?  if so use `nrow(df)`

Comment: No, I'm trying to count the number of tme each result appears. For example, if I had a vector x <- c("Jim", "and", "me", "bought", " some", "Ben", "and", "Jerrys") I want to get their frequencies. e.g. c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1)

Comment: `table` doesn't stop counting - the default print behavior just truncates it off. Try `tt = table(runif(6000))`, `length(tt)`, `head(tt)`, `tail(tt)`...

Comment: Do you want a count column in `df`? If so, try `aggregate(. ~ string, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`. Otherwise, as @Gregor says, `table` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this won't be popular, but in the end I achieved the desired result with a for loop and and taking the number of rows in a subset.

```
y <- as.numeric(vector())
x <- as.numeric(vector())
for (i in test$token){
x <- as.numeric(nrow(df[(df$token == i),]))

y <- c(y, x)

}
```

Y then becomes a vector with the number of occurences of each string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor noticed it seems like you interpreted the `table` output wrongly whereas it is actually doing the right counting. Anyway here goes a solution using `Reduce`, you should replace `df` where indicated by your dataframe and `string` column name by the column name of your actual dataframe in which you are counting.

```
# let's create some dataframe with three strings randomly distributed of length 1000
df <- data.frame(string = unlist(lapply(round(runif(1000, 1, 3)), function(i) c('hi', 'ok', 'my cat')[i])))
my.count <- function(word, df) {
  # now let's count how many 'b' we found
  Reduce(function(acc, r) {
    # replace 'string' by the name of the column of your dataframe over which you want to count
    if(r$string == word)
      acc + 1
    else
      acc
  }, apply(df, 1, as.list), init = 0)
}

# count how many 'my cat' strings are in the df dataframe at column 'string', replace with yours
my.count('my cat', df)
# now let's try to find the frequency of all of them
uniq <- unique(df$string)
freq <- unlist(lapply(uniq, my.count, df))
names(freq) <- uniq
freq
# output 
# ok my cat     hi 
# 490    261    249
# we can check indeed that the sum is 1000
sum(freq)
# [1] 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this with any sized data frame is to add a `count` field to the data frame and then summarize the `string` field by `count` with the `doBy` package - like so:

```
require(doBy)
df$count <- 1
result <- summaryBy(count ~ string, data = df, FUN = sum, keep.names = TRUE)
```